# Control evaluation for functional constraints

Tags: hold, constraint, findinstance

I'm trying to understand how to use Mathematica to find a solution subject to constraints, where one of the constraints is specified as a predicate function. But I don't know how to control evaluation in order to use the predicate function as a condition.

Here's the problem. I want to find three integers, $a$, $b$, and $c$, subject to these constraints:

1. They sum to 70
2. Each of the integer is greater than or equal to 15 and less than 30
3. No digits from 1-9 appears twice if you consider all the digits in the squares of the integers.

So how do I approach this with Mathematica? I expect I can use `FindInstance` to find values under a set of constraints.

I can express constraints 1 and 2 by setting variables equal to equations and inequalities:

```
eq = (a + b + c == 70);
cs = 15 <= a <= 30 && 15 <= b <= 30 && 15 <= c <= 30;
```

In order to express the third constraint, I have defined this predicate function, which takes a list of numbers and returns true when they do not re-use digits:

```
UniqueDigitsQ[xss_] := With[
  {nonzeros = Select[Flatten[Map[IntegerDigits,xss]] ,#1!=0&]},
  SortBy[Tally[nonzeros],Last][[-1,-1]] <2];
```

So I would like to be able to express the third constraint by saying:

```
cs2 = UniqueDigitsQ[ {a^2,b^2,c^2} ];
```

But this fails, because the predicate function cannot handle symbolic argument.

Is there a way to fix this problem by defining the function in such a way that it does not evaluate until the arguments are numeric? Or else, what is the right approach?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Find all solutions for the first two criteria then select from those the ones that meet the third criteria.

```
sol = Select[
  Solve[{a + b + c == 70, 15 <= a < 30, 15 <= b < 30, 
    15 <= c < 30}, {a, b, c}, Integers],
  (digits = Flatten[IntegerDigits[{a^2, b^2, c^2}] /. #];
    Length[digits] == Length[Union@digits]) &]

(* {{a -> 19, b -> 23, c -> 28}, {a -> 19, b -> 28, c -> 23}, {a -> 23, 
  b -> 19, c -> 28}, {a -> 23, b -> 28, c -> 19}, {a -> 28, b -> 19, 
  c -> 23}, {a -> 28, b -> 23, c -> 19}} *)
```

These are just permutations of `{19, 23, 28}`

**EDIT:** A user-defined function must be used in an equation or an inequality. Consequently, modify your function to return a numeric value.

```
UniqueDigitsQ[xss_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := With[
  {nonzeros = Select[Flatten[Map[IntegerDigits, xss]], #1 != 0 &]}, 
   Boole[SortBy[Tally[nonzeros], Last][[-1, -1]] < 2]];

Solve[{a + b + c == 70, 15 <= a < 30, 15 <= b < 30, 15 <= c < 30,
  UniqueDigitsQ[{a^2, b^2, c^2}] == 1}, {a, b, c}, Integers]

(* {{a -> 19, b -> 23, c -> 28}, {a -> 19, b -> 28, c -> 23}, {a -> 23, b -> 19, 
  c -> 28}, {a -> 23, b -> 28, c -> 19}, {a -> 28, b -> 19, 
  c -> 23}, {a -> 28, b -> 23, c -> 19}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this a better way because Mathematica’s solvers work only with equations and inequalities, and not user-defined functions? Or is it that it’s dangerous to use substitutions with user-defined functions at all? Functions are obviously a basic form of abstraction, so I’d like to understand how to use them in this sort of case because usually it becomes untenable to express everything in an inline snippet of code.

Comment: The solvers can work with user-defined functions. I just find the approach that I used simple and straightforward. You could also eliminate the redundancy of the permutations by adding a fourth constraint that the values are ordered, e.g., `a < b < c`. Note that the third constraint eliminates any equality.

Comment: Oh I quite agree your approach is simpler and better! I just remain curious how my kind of approach would work, since sometimes function-defined constraints will be unavoidable, and I wonder if the solver can work with them efficiently or if it can only work analytically with equations and then you have to brute force search over functions. 

Also, even if the solver could handle UDFs, I think it couldn’t handle mine because mine consumes symbolic arguments eagerly, before substitution rules are applied, unlike IntegerDigits apparently. This is the evaluation behavior I don’t understand.